# ActionBar Navigation with Google Music Style

Tags: android, android-layout, android-actionbar, android-spinner, android-navigation

I'm trying to create Navigation at ActionBar with Google Music Style.

[image]

I've tried 2 different ways how to do it, but no one satisfied me at all:

1. Set `bar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_LIST)` and connect it with `SpinnerAdapter`. It seems quite good, but I want 2 rows in `DropDownMenu`.
   [image]
2. Create my own ActionBar layout with `Spinner` inside, but It's underlined and icon is missing. It's even harder to work with and more messy solution then first approach.[image]

Has anyone idea how to solve this problem? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I had answered it [here][1] Please check that code. 


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19020329/how-to-add-spinner-to-subtitle-as-in-the-play-music-app-for-android

Comment: Do you solved it, @skywall?