# Add dropdown menu to android Action bar

Tags: android, android-actionbar, menuitem

I am developing my first android app. I would like to add a dropdown menu to action bar. I used the second option described in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8312344/how-to-add-a-dropdown-item-on-the-action-bar), but I am not able to set the onItemSelectedListner. I am using the tab navigation, so I can't set the navigation to listview. How can I get this to work?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20017840/how-to-combine-navigation-drawer-and-spinner-like-in-google-app/20017862#20017862 .Looking for spinner?

Comment: http://www.androidhive.info/2013/11/android-working-with-action-bar/