# How to update the Drop-down Navigation title when user selects an option?

Tags: android, drop-down-menu, android-actionbar, spinner

I have a Drop-down Navigation (Spinner) in my Action Bar.

For creating the spinner, I used the code below, on my onCreate() method:

```
//SPINNER
    SpinnerAdapter mSpinnerAdapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.main_options,
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_LIST);
    getActionBar().setListNavigationCallbacks(mSpinnerAdapter,this);
```

main_options is a array in strings.xml resources, and has 3 options, which are shown on the Drop-down Navigation list (Spinner) when Activity is shown. Currently, the first option appears as "selected".

When I choose an option of the spinner list, it show an Toast message.

Current code of the method *onNavigationItemSelected()*:

```
    @Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(int arg0, long arg1) {
   Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext()," text",1000).show();
    return true;
}
```

I want to modify it to refresh the activity (for this, I will call onRestart() method), but also: I want to **update the title of the Drop-down list for the current selected option**.

How can I do it?

Comment: P.S. In my Activity, I have a GridView with GridView adapter. I want to refresh the page and the spinner title according to the selected option. I've tryed to change it into Fragments but the solution did not work, too (error in replace function). I want to stay with the Activity approac, just refreshing the Activity, but I dont know how to know how to update the Spinner title dinamically.