# How to add spinner to Action bar with tabs and fragments?

Tags: android, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock

I want to add spinner to action bar to use it as filter drop down , I am using tabs with fragments on my app .

Any hint is very much appreciated .

Comment: Looking for this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20017840/how-to-combine-navigation-drawer-and-spinner-like-in-google-app. Modify according to your requirements. only missing tabs

Answer (score 2):

You can Use this [link..](http://developer.android.com/design/building-blocks/spinners.html)

i mean Actually someone will defenately Donwvote Your Question and My answer But ..

user can use this links to Use a Dropdown list(snipper) 
[1.android dropdown navigation..](http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/adding-drop-down-navigation-to-action-bar-in-android/)
[2.android  customize action bars](http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2011/04/customizing-action-bar.html)
[3. android sample dropdown](http://www.java-samples.com/showtutorial.php?tutorialid=1517)

If you want more Please design post a Expected out put using paint.. that will be helpful to every one..